# Suppose $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$ are onto functions. Show that $g \circ f: X \to Z$ is onto

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I feel like my solution isn't sufficient at the moment.
-->

For some x in X there exists a y in Y given by $ f(x)=y $ because $f: X \to Y$ is onto.

The same can be said for some y in Y existing as a z in Z given by the function $ g(y) = z $ because g is onto.

Therefore, applying g to f will map X onto Z.

[f(x) = y][                g(y) = z ]
[
g(f(x)) = g(y) = z ]

Comment: A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is called *onto* if for all $b \in B$ there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. So, if $g$ is *onto*, you have that for each $z \in Z$ there is a $y \in Y$ such that $g(y) = z$. But again, for each $y \in Y$ there is an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. So now, consider $g[f(x)]$ ...

Answer (score 2):

**(1):** If $f: X\to Y$ is onto so $$\forall y\in Y, \exists x\in X,~ f(x)=y$$

**(2):** If $g: Y\to Z$ is onto so $$\forall z\in Z, \exists y\in Y,~ f(y)=z$$

Now, assume that $z\in Z$ is an arbitrary element. By (2), we can find an element $y\in Y$ such that $$g(y)=z$$ But $y\in Y$, so by (1), we can find an $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Therefore:

$$f(x)=y \wedge g(y)=z\Longrightarrow g(f(x))=z$$ or $$g\circ f(x)=z$$

Comment: Nice avatar but I tried to read the sentence and I could not:)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: یا علی ابن موسی الرضا المرتضی  :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $(g \circ f) (X) = g(f(X))$

(By definition, a map $\varphi \colon A \to B$ is surjective if and only if $\varphi(A) = B$.)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea; you just aren't quite there yet!  I would do things in a slightly different order.

You need to show that for any $z\in Z$, there is an $x\in X$ such that $g\circ f(x)=z$.

Start by noting (as you did) that because $g$ is onto, there is a $y\in Y$ such that $g(y)=z$. Now, because $f$ is onto, there is an $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Then for these $x$ and $y$, we have
$$
g\circ f(x)=g(f(x))=g(y)=z.
$$
Since you can do this for any $z\in Z$, you have shown that $g\circ f:X\to Z$ is an onto function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start here:

> For some $x\in X$ there exists a $y\in Y$ given by $f(x) = y$ because $f : X\to Y$ is onto.

(I may have "fixed" the notation a bit.)
The first part is always true---that's how functions work, so the "because" doesn't quite match.  The onto part allows you to go the other way: For every $y\in Y$ there exists an $x\in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. That's the direction you want to approach "onto" from -- start with the range and show that it is in the image of the function.  So if you want to show that you have a mapping from $X$ _onto $Z$, you need to start with an arbitrary element of $Z$ and find the corresponding element of $X$.